# Animate UIButton state change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I'm using a UIButton with images for normal and highlighted states. They work as expected but I want to have some fading/merging transition and not just a sudden swap.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

This can be done using transition animation of a UIView. It does not matter the `isHighlighted` property is not animatable, because it transitions the whole view.

#### Swift 3

```
UIView.transition(with: button,
                  duration: 4.0,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                  animations: { button.isHighlighted = true },
                  completion: nil)
```

#### Objective-C

```
[UIView transitionWithView:button
                  duration:4.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{ button.highlighted = YES; }
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: I don't think the `highlighted` property is animatable.

Comment: @Marty `highlighted` property is not animatable, therefore `+transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` must be used instead of `+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`.

Comment: as mentioned isHighlighted is not an animatable property in iOS

Comment: @Jerland2 as mentioned, `transition(with: UIView...)` does not care a property is not animatable, because it transitions the whole view.

Comment: The secret here is in the `.transitionCrossDissolve`. Other animation styles do not reliably animate. @MariánČerný - I'd suggest you expand this example with an idea of _where_ to perform this, e.g. inside of `... isHighlighted { didSet {} }`

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish that I extended UIButton. added a new property called hilightedImage with the following code:

```
- (void)setHilightImage:(UIImageView *)_hilightImage
{
    if (hilightImage != _hilightImage) {
        [hilightImage release];
        hilightImage = [_hilightImage retain];
    }
    [hilightImage setAlpha:0];
    [self addSubview:hilightImage];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.14];
    if(hilightImage){
        [hilightImage setAlpha:1];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    self.highlighted = FALSE;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.14];
    if(hilightImage){
        [hilightImage setAlpha:0];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a subclass, not an extension?

Comment: marty, you can say "extended" to mean "I made a new class...", just as in the example.

Answer (score 2):

`UIButton` inherits from `UIView`

So then you get its view and call `beginAnimations:context:`

Then all the appropriate setAnimation methods from there.

The following properties of the `UIView` class are animatable:

- @property frame
- @property bounds
- @property center
- @property transform
- @property alpha
- @property backgroundColor
- @property contentStretch

Ref: [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView!)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a self contained solution that also supports a boolean `animated` flag.

```
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  if (_button.enabled == enabled) {
    return;
  }

  void (^transitionBlock)(void) = ^void(void) {
    _button.enabled = enabled;
  };

  if (animated) {
    [UIView transitionWithView:_button
                      duration:0.15
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                      transitionBlock();
                    }
                    completion:nil];
  } else {
    transitionBlock();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**@marián-Černý** answer in **Swift**:

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.transitionWithView(button, 
    duration: 4.0, 
    options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, 
    animations: { button.highlighted = true },
    completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.transition(with: button, 
    duration: 4.0, 
    options: .transitionCrossDissolve, 
    animations: { button.isHighlighted = true },
    completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're coming here after iOS 15 and use the new `UIButton.Configuration`, you might be using `configurationUpdateHandler` to determine and set the confiration. What you can do in such a case is to set the configuration (probably the last thing you do in your function), using the `UIView.transition(with: button` API, so something like this:

```swift
UIView.transition(with: button,
                  duration: 0.2,
                  options: [.transitionCrossDissolve,
                            .beginFromCurrentState,
                            .allowUserInteraction,
                            .curveEaseInOut],
                  animations: { button.configuration = configuration })
```

Answer (score 0):

using CustomButton instead of `UIButton` and overriding `isHighlighted` property worked for me;

```
class KeypadButton: UIButton {
    var highlightDuration: TimeInterval = 0.25
    
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if oldValue == false && isHighlighted {
                highlight()
            } else if oldValue == true && !isHighlighted {
                unHighlight()
            }
        }
    }

    func highlight() {
        animateBackground(to: highlightedBackgroundColor, duration: highlightDuration)
    }

    func unHighlight() {
        animateBackground(to: normalBackgroundColor, duration: highlightDuration)
    }
    
    private func animateBackground(to color: UIColor?, duration: TimeInterval) {
        guard let color = color else { return }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: highlightDuration) {
            self.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
}
```