# How to achieve smooth transition when image of button changes between states?

Tags: ios, uibutton

In iOS, we use the UIView animate block for tyo make chnages to properties of any control and that happens with a smooth transition.

Is it possible to achieve that when images of different state changes for UIButtons ?
What I can think of as of now is to manually change the image or state in animation block.

Is there a simpler way at the interface builder level or may be at code level so that I dont have to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Stackoverflow answer
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6218432/904355)

I would subclass UIButton like in this answer so you only need to write the code once.